# How can I bundle files and folders into a single unit without zipping them?

Tags: c#, archive, zip, cab

I have to move data to a device that does not have a lot of storage space.

The data is multiple files of different sizes and formats.

When I zip them, transfer them to the device and unzip them, twice the storage space is used.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: If you can't create a direct connection then no.  If you have to transfer the 'blob' to the device to 'unblob' it, it will always take more space.  If the device has internet access, you could download the files from a web site.  If the device has a USB slot, you could plug in a usb drive.

Comment: So you want to somehow bundle multiple files into one, transfer this new bundle file and then unbundle the file to the original files?

Comment: A ZIP file has a catalog at the end, therefore you usually have to save the file before you can extract it. Use a TAR or CPIO file, it can be extracted 'on the fly', and you don't need to save the intermediate archive.

Comment: Why not just transfer the files individually (i.e. one by one)?

Comment: @Ackdari If there was a way to transfer without a bundle would also be good. Say like streaming a folder?